# ¿Cómo se leen los nombres de los reyes?

Tags: pronunciación, números

A veces, cuando voy al trabajo en coche, me da por poner el GPS aunque sea un trayecto de solo 15 minutos. Y cada vez que llego a *P.º Alfonso **XIII***, la vocecita del GPS se emperra en decir:

> Tome la cuarta salida en dirección *Paseo Alfonso **decimotercero***.

Lo cual me chirría un poco, porque aquí esa vía se conoce como *Paseo Alfonso **trece***, y otros nombres como por ejemplo Luis XIV o Juan XXIII se suelen pronunciar como *Luis **catorce*** o *Juan **veintitrés*** (o al menos yo siempre los he leído así).

Sin embargo, no deja de ser cierto que el ordinal para "13" es "decimotercero/a". Y el [artículo del DPD sobre números romanos](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=QHaq7I8KrD6FQAyXTS#3) no aclara si se leen distinto que los números normales.

¿Quién tiene razón: el GPS o yo?

Comment: Curioso entonces que nuestro rey actual sea Felipe sexto, y no Felipe seis. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

El DPD te da la respuesta en su artículo [*cardinales*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=rqV8h362gD62vc21qB):

> En el caso de las series de papas y reyes con igual nombre, se utilizan, en la escritura, los números romanos (→ [números, 3](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=QHaq7I8KrD6FQAyXTS#3)), que **se leen como ordinales hasta el número diez (aunque en este último caso puede usarse también el cardinal)**: *Felipe IV* (se lee *Felipe cuarto*), *Enrique VIII* (*Enrique octavo*), *Alfonso X* (*Alfonso décimo* o *diez*); **pero a partir del diez se leen siempre como cardinales**: *Luis XVI* (*Luis dieciséis*), *Juan XXIII* (*Juan veintitrés*).

Es decir:

- De I a IX: se usa el ordinal.
- X: se puede usar el ordinal o el cardinal (*diez* o *décimo*).
- A partir de XI: se usa el cardinal (*once*, *doce*...).

Por tanto, el GPS no tiene razón y debería indicar *Paseo Alfonso trece*, si bien deberías admitirle *Alfonso décimo* cuando tú digas *Alfonso diez*.

Comment: @walen Penélope, siempre tejiendo debates...

Comment: Which raises the additional question - why change? Does Spanish avoid the ordinals elsewhere?

Comment: @mdewey probably because it starts being a long word? It is interesting that in other cases the rule differs: _Se escribirán preferentemente con letras: a) Los números que pueden expresarse en una sola palabra, esto es, del cero al veintinueve, las decenas (treinta, cuarenta, etc.) y las centenas (cien, doscientos, etc.)_  and _c) Los números que se expresan en dos palabras unidas por la conjunción_ ([números](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=QHaq7I8KrD6FQAyXTS)).

Comment: Puede que esa sea la regla pero si el origen de ese numerito es irlos contando "segundo, tercero, cuarto, ..." debería haber consistencia y se deberían usar los ordinales siempre. Parece que el motivo es lo que dice @fedorqui las palabras comienzan a ser muy largas y nos da **física pereza**.  En este caso yo estaría del lado de la vocecita del GPS :-)